# Scss variable not resolving to actual value

Tags: sass, scss-functions

After initializing a scss variable with a css variable and a fallback value using this manner

```
$BaseFontSize: var(--BaseFontSize, 10px);
```

I am trying to use `BaseFontSize` in a function, but it throws the following error:

> Error: Undefined operation "40px/var(--BaseFontSize, 10px) * 1rem".

The function which is throwing the error:

```
@function px-to-rem($px) {
  $convertedValue: ($px / $BaseFontSize) * 1rem;
  @return $convertedValue;
}
```

Usage in Code:

```
.className{
  padding: px-to-rem(40px);
}
```

Comment: A CSS variable is not a SASS one? SASS does not know how to handle these. Or at least, it didnt back in the day and I doubt they would now...

Comment: The scss variable works fine when used like 
font-size: $BaseFontSize;

Comment: Yes, because the sass variable contains a css variable descriptor. Sass just doesn’t know what it means, as its just text with no sass meaning.

Answer (score 2):

CSS variables are only resolved during runtime; when CSS styles are applied and a DOM exists. (the DOM nesting is relevant for variable resolution)

SCSS variables, functions, and mixins are purely SASS preprocessor features and are resolved/executed only during the build process. At that point in time there is no DOM, no nesting, and no applied css styles; and SASS treats the value assigned to your SCSS variable as merely a string.

```scss
$base-font-size: var(--base-font-size, 10px);
```

is treated exactly like

```scss
$base-font-size: "var(--base-font-size, 10px)";
```

Comment: so are there any workaround to achieve the results? I want to convert pixel to rem based on base font size provided.

Comment: Obviously, not with css variables as sass functions are computed at compile, not runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could update your function and how you use it to achieve a similar result:

You will need to remove the unit from your css variable, and the argument passed to the function: `--BaseFontSize: 16;`, `font-size: px-to-rem(32);`
.

Then, update the function to use `calc()`: `calc(#{$px}rem / var(--BaseFontSize));`.

```
:root {
  --BaseFontSize: 16;
}

$BaseFontSize: var(--BaseFontSize);

@function px-to-rem($px) {
  @return calc(#{$px}rem / var(--BaseFontSize));
}

p {
  font-size: px-to-rem(32);
}
```

The compiled CSS will look like this:

```
:root {
  --BaseFontSize: 16;
}

p {
  font-size: calc(32rem / var(--BaseFontSize));
}
```